# Bitbucket: fork to existing repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-fork

I have empty repository B on bitbucket and I want to fork another one A into my existing repository B. How can I do this? On website bitbucket allows only to fork in new repository.

Comment: Why don't you just delete repo B and fork to a new repo and name it what repo B was called? If repo B is empty, it doesn't matter if you delete it. Unless there is more to your problem...

Comment: Because repository B already has lot of information in wiki and my task is try to use it for fork... That's sad.

Comment: @Chris I just created new repository.

Answer (score 3):

I see two options:

1. If you don't need Bitbucket to call it a fork you can simply clone repository A and push it to repository B. This is most of what a "fork" is.

   ```
   git clone git@bitbucket.com:user/repo
   cd repo
   git remote add my-clone git@bitbucket.com:you/repo-b
   git push --mirror my-clone
   ```
2. If you need Bitbucket to call your fork a fork, you can take advantage of the fact that [Bitbucket wikis are repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-and-edit-pages-317195798.html) to make a local copy of your wiki, then delete repository B, then fork repository A to repository B, then push the wiki back to repository B.

   ```
   git clone http://bitbucket.org/you/repo-b/wiki repo-b.wiki
   cd repo-b.wiki
   # Have a look at the files in repo-b.wiki and make sure they look complete
   # Then delete repository B from Bitbucket
   # Then fork repository A to repsitory B using the Bitbucket web UI
   # Then push the wiki back:
   git push origin master
   ```